# How to handle Mui Dialog open/close without manipulating state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I set Debug Mode with react context api. When Debug mode is activated by a shortcut,an Dialog pops up to inform the user that debug mode is now active. After clicking ok the debug mode is still active.
My Problem is that i need to close the dialog without deactivating debug mode. Since the open property depends on the Context the dialog will only be closed when i set debugMode to false, but this would be unexpected behaviour.

```
function App() {
  const { isInDebugMode } = useDebugModeContext();

  return (
    <Box width={700} height={300}>
      <Dialog open={isInDebugMode}>
        <DialogTitle>Debug Mode</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          You are now in Debug Mode. Press Ctrl + D to leave.
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={() => {}}>Ok</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I think i need another state or variable that depends on the Debug Mode Context to correct the dialog closing behaviour

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
  const { isInDebugMode } = useDebugModeContext();
  const [debugVisible, setDebugVisible] = useState<boolean>(true);

  return (
    <Box width={700} height={300}>
      <Dialog open={isInDebugMode && debugVisible}>
        <DialogTitle>Debug Mode</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          You are now in Debug Mode. Press Ctrl + D to leave.
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              setDebugVisible(false);
            }}
          >
            Ok
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

This is a temporary solution. So the debug Mode remains activated and i can close the dialog.

Comment: I like to name boolean state variables with a prefix of "is" just to remind me that the variable contains a boolean. I would therefore name your new state variable and its setter as "isDebugVisible" and "setIsDebugVisible". As a further convenience, I often add a method like "isDebugVisibleNegate" that in turn sets "isDebugVisible" to false. You can then simplify the "onClick" property of the Button so that it is "onClick={isDebugVisibleNegate}".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, going to update my solution soon.